# How to get client ip in Kubernetes hosted application?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rancher

I have an application made of a few microservices. UI has is served via Nginx and accesses the API via reverse proxy. This is a local Kubernetes deployed with Rancher.

UI service is NodePort so I can access it outside of the cluster and API can be either NodePort or ClusterIP. In API microservice there is an IP logger that always shows the IP of the Node on which the UI is deployed, no matter what I'm doing.

So far I did try 'externalTrafficPolicy: Local' for the NodePort services in combination with setting Nginx headers (X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto) for reverse proxying. Nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to get client IP in the application hosted in Kubernetes?

Kubernetes Version: v1.17.3

Rancher v2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` and then look at the actual `REMOTE_ADDRESS` or whatever your web framework calls it.

Comment: I did exactly that as written in the question. My rough guess is that NGINX ingress causing it since it is the only thing before my services.

Comment: Oh, you didn't say you were using an ingress, you said "served via Nginx"? You'll have to specifically configure any proxy to be aware of this.